# Error retrieving email address using facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to retrieve a email address of a user by calling facebook api.
I am using

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email', function(response) {
var txt="Email:"+response.email;
var element=document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=txt;
    });
```

code to retrieve a email address.

I have asked for email permission during login as follows:-

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

    FB.login({scope: 'email'});
    } else {
  FB.login({scope: 'email'});
    }
  });
  };
```

Still when I print email id it shows "undefined".

Comment: Log your access token that you get during login to the console, and check here whether it really has `email` permission included here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Is the first Javascript executed after the FB SDK has been loaded, and after you checked whether the user is logged in?

Comment: @CBroe How to get a user's access token?

Comment: @Tobi yes,the first javascript is loaded after the FB SDK has been loaded.

Comment: @CBroe I will like to have answer for "How to get a user's access token?" from your side if you can give some time.

Comment: If you’re not familiar with the basics, please start reading the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: @CBroe I am familiar with the basics and in javascript to call a FB API we call FB.api and I pass /me as access token and that works fine as it gave me a response object but i havent came across storing an access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have got answer to my problem.
If you are using Facebook's Button code then You have to add extra permissions as an array. What i was doing was that calling the Login Function manually with permissions but forgot to add permissions as a scope in button code.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="5" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" scope=['email'] data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```